# CodeIgniter: Upload Image to path and database

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload

I'm trying to upload an image to a file path and insert that path to the database. However, the upload always shows the error **You did not select a file to upload** ..even though I did.

**Here's my VIEW**

```
<form action="<?= site_url('profile/profile_submit')?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" class="image-upload" accept="image/*" name="profilePic" id="profilePic"/>
</form>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'assets/img/profile_img/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
$config['max_size'] = "2048000"; 
$config['max_height'] = "768";
$config['max_width'] = "1024";
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('profilePic')){
        $data = $this->upload->data();
            $picture = array(
                'photoPath' => $this->upload->data('full_path').$data['file_name']
            );
    }
    else{
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
    } 

$this->profile_model->submit_profile($picture);
```

**MODEL**

```
function submit_profile($picture){
        $this->db->insert('tbl_st_picture', $picture);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your upload code as below. Don't use `$this->input->post()` for getting file data. Also make sure you have added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form

```
if ($this->upload->do_upload('profilePic')){
       $data = $this->upload->data();
        $picture = array(
                'photoPath' => $this->upload->data('full_path').$data['file_name'],
        );
    }
    else{
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
```

Comment: i'm using helpers , im using this form_open_multipart('profile/profile_submit')

Comment: Will you show your updated code and form tag in view?

Answer (score 2):

```
public function add() { 
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $config['upload_path'] = "./assets/uploads/";
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpeg|png|jpg';
    $config['max_height'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width'] = '2048';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    $this->path = './assets/uploads/';

   $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (! $this->upload->do_upload('berkas'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        redirect(base_url().'berita/tambah');
    }else{
        $dataUpload = $this->upload->data();

        $data = array(
            'Judul' => $this->input->post('Judul'),
            'Foto' => $dataUpload['file_name'],
            'Isi' => $this->input->post('Isi')
            );
        $this->load->model('berita_model');
        $result = $this->berita_model->insert('berita',$data);

        if ($result>0) {
            redirect(base_url() .'news');
        } else {
            echo "Gagal";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: function insert ($db,$data){
        $result = $this->db->insert($db,$data);
        return $result;
    }

Comment: these is my model

Answer (score 1):

if you want, you can try this.

```
function file_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';

    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('Upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a folder name upload into the root path in your project.

Answer (score 0):

This how it should be done:

`$this->upload->do_upload('profilePic')`

The do_upload function does the necessary posting for you.

Comment: a tried $this->upload->do_upload('profilePic') , still the same error. I updated my code above

Comment: well I copied and pasted your *exact* code into my localhost CI and it works fine and the images upload (did you verify if the images are in the folder?). beware if you refresh the controller page with the upload code of course you will get an error as there is no post data then. further for `photoPath` you just do `$data['full_path']` it already contains the filename.

Comment: Also note that if `assets/img/profile_img/` does not exist it will also fail (although I'm not sure what the error message is). CI doesn't create the upload folder, you have to do that yourself.

Comment: assets/img/profile_img/ exist. and I've changed the $data['full_path']. still not uploading tho;